# How to remove a header row from a csv file using SSIS and SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

I have an SSIS package written in Visual Studio 2008 that runs a few stored procedures and places the results in files.  These files are then sent off to a vendor.  All of the files were created with header rows.  One of these files should not be sent with a header row.

I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was writing my question while I was testing out an answer.  I decided, since I hadn't seen the question on StackOverflow, I would just ask it anyway and then answer it with with what I found.

Here are the steps I took:

- I removed the header row from the base file.
- In the Flat File Connection Editor, I unchecked the Column names in the first data row box.
- I previewed the file and it looked good.
- In the Flat File destination editor, I remapped the columns.
- I re-ran the package and the csv file was created without a header row.

Answer (score 3):

Yes the trick is not to check the "Column names in the first data row" at the Flat File Connection Manager Editor

[image]